# Send serialized data plus other parameters doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to write this:

```
$.ajax({
        url:webPath + '/ajax/list_filter.php',
        data:{form:serializedForm,userId:localStorage['userId'],code:localStorage['code'],refreshType:refreshType},
        type:'POST'
    }).done(function(data){
        //do stuff with data 
    });
```

Now pay attention to serializedForm which comes from, as the name says, a serialised form. The problem is that the serializedForm is passed as a string and PHP doesn't parse it in a correct way, it sees the other variables sent correctly and form as only one big string.
How can I solve this problem, still using the very handy jQuery .serialize() method?

Comment: What is `serializedForm`?  JSON?  Check `json_decode()`.

Comment: This is my typical serialised form **formData:sex=F&gay=ckd&search_1=&search_2=&search_3=gonna+rossa&search_4=&search_5=** .serialize() doesn't convert to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would just change:

```
data:{form:serializedForm,userId:localStorage['userId'],code:localStorage['code'],refreshType:refreshType}
```

to

```
data:serializedForm+'&userId='+encodeURIComponent(localStorage.userId)+'&code='+encodeURIComponent(localStorage.code)+'&refreshType='+encodeURIComponent(refreshType)
```

This should keep your data out of arrays within arrays, as well.